# Using postman + oauth2 to access Google Apps Admin SDK

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-admin-sdk, postman

I am struggling to get oauth2 working between postman and the Google Apps Admin Sdk. I have created a client app in the google console and set the Authorized redirect URIs to `https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback` and my settings in postman are as follows

```
Auth URL          - https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
Access Token URL  - https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
Client Id         - some id here
Client Secrent    - some secret here
Scope             - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
Token Name        - Google
Grant Type        - Authorization Code
Request Access Token Locally - Checked
```

This returns a token - `xyz` - after logging in.

I do a `GET` request with the token in the url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?key=xyz
```

The error I am getting is below

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Login Required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Login Required"
  }
}
```

From what I have read this should work. Where else do I have to login? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around I figured out my url was incorrect. Changing `key` to `access_token` did the trick.

Just a side note, ensure you specify the `domain` or `customer` parameter otherwise you will receive a bad request error.